# Alternative to IMEI in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch

I am developing a banking app.
The functionality is

1. User will fill out registration in a form. He/She will provide a unique device identifier  (like IMEI, or serial) number. The identifier length should be user-friendly.  For Android apps it's already done with the IMEI number.
2. The bank will keep this unique device identifier on file for this account. So the number must be appear on the device and should have a maximum length of 15.
3. When a user logs in from the app, we will send  this device identifier every time.
4. When the user resets the phone, the identifier will remain the same.

For security reasons,
we do not save any data locally. The bank requires that every time we pick up the identifier programmatically.

We don’t permit using the mobile number as an alternative to IMEI .

What can we use for this?

Comment: the only option is the identifierForVendor, but it's bigger than 15 chars, BTW, not all android devices have IMEI, you should look for an alternative in such cases

Comment: I can recommend article about unique identifiers: https://possiblemobile.com/2013/04/unique-identifiers/ Try find out which way suit your requirements better. I think you will need find compromise with your bunk, because I see only two ways: 1. Store in keychain generated 15-characters id or 2. use `identifierForVendor` which is longer then 15 chars.

Comment: Thank @Cy-4AH . 
I am new in IOS era . 
I have visited this site . UDID is might  better as aspect of my purpose . But its deprecated by apple . The next favour solution are Identifier for Vendor , AdID . But both them are lose after reset the device .
The issues is would you suggest something like that which is constant , static even after resetting the app .

Comment: `identifierForVendor` and record in keychain will be constant, even after resetting app. They will be reseted only after resetting device to fabric state. Which is quite good, because will be reseted all users data even in keychain and with such clean device it's not big problem, that bank recognize it like new device.